# Enabling Location Reporting disables itself

Tags: location-services, android-wear

I'm trying to enable Location Reporting such that I can use it with my Moto 360 for tracking stuff. Whenever I enable Location Reporting in the Google Settings app it immediately turns itself off again.

I looked in the [docs](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/3118687) and noticed this:

[image]

I'm in Spain, and I know "Ok Maps" for offline maps doesn't work here. Could that be it?
It's also an Apps account, but I couldn't find any settings to enable or disable this in the admin panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue may actually be the fact you are in Spain. I've come across issues with others in the country, including (as you mentioned) the fact that you cannot download offline maps in Google Maps.

This appears (though it's not fully clear) to be down to licencing / legal issues around the mapping. Even a few metres over the Spanish border and everything works again.

Comment: Thanks, I feared as much. I wonder if I complain loudly enough Google will sort it :D

Comment: @daentech it's worth a try I guess, but I'm sure it's a known issue!